# Google Maps API v3 – Multiple Markers, Multiple Infowindows-Server Side VB.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project using google maps api v3 and server side vb.net and am trying to make it so when a marker is clicked on a infowindow appears. I have accomplished this but now what i want is different content to be displayed when different markers are clicked on which i can't seem to figure out.

```
var markers = [

<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
            {
            "JSN": '<%# Eval("JSN") %>',
            "Address": "<%# Eval("Address") %>",
            "Postcode": "<%# Eval("Postcode") %>",
            "StartTime": "<%# Eval("StartTime") %>",
             "TownCity": "<%# Eval("TownCity") %>",
              "County": "<%# Eval("County") %>"
        }
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
    ,
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
];



 function loadDefaultMap(lat,lng,index) {
 var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
 }


        function addMarkers() {
        // get address
        // In loop get each address (latitude,longitude)
        // call loadMap in each iteration
        if(markers.length >0){

        /// ******************************** INITIALIZING  **********************
         var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.630886,1.297355),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var infoWindow = null;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        /// *********************************************************************

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

            var data = markers[i];
            var icon='';            
            var Time=data.StartTime.split(':');

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

            content:markers[i].Address +"<br><b> "+markers[i].TownCity+" </b>"+ markers[i].County
            });
            if(Time[0] > 00 && Time[0] < 11){
             icon= '../../../Images/blue.png'
            }
            else
            {
             icon= '../../../Images/red.png'
            }
            var adrs= data.Address +" "+data.TownCity+" "+ data.County
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': adrs }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                   var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                   var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                   //********************ADDING MARKER****************************

                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.Address +" "+data.TownCity+" "+ data.County,
                    icon: icon
                });



                (function (marker, data) {
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.open(map, this);
                    });
                })(marker, data);
                   //*************************************************************

                }

        });
        }
        }else{
        loadDefaultMap(52.630886,1.297355,-1);
        }
        }

    function pageLoad() {         
        addMarkers();
   }
```

This always showed the last marker that was bound to map so the info window always appeared on the last marker.  i als try this but its not working.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var marker = markers[i];
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
infowindow.setContent(this.html);
infowindow.open(map, this);

});

}
```

any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps - Multiple markers - 1 InfoWindow problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402667/google-maps-multiple-markers-1-infowindow-problem)

Comment: i tried this, and it doesn't make a difference

Comment: You need function closure for the geocode operation also.  However, be aware if you have more than about 10 markers, you will encounter OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors. [One of the many qnswers that deals with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866028/gmaps-api-v3-multiple-markers-infowindow-problem/12572502#12572502).